# Facing issue while connecting to hsql server if I create hsql server through java code

Tags: hsqldb

I want to create hsql server through java code.I dont want to use server.properties to specify my properties. Instead I am trying to specify properties through HSQLProperties.
Below is my code for creating server.

`HsqlProperties p = new HsqlProperties();
        p.setProperty("server.database.0","file:/sampledb/ipl5;user=user;password=password");
        p.setProperty("server.dbname.0","ipl5");
        Server server = new Server();
        server.setProperties(p);`

but when I try to connect to the started server through client call ,

`conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost/ipl5","user","password");`

I get following stacktrace:

```
java.sql.SQLException: General error: database alias does not exist
at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCConnection.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:582)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:185)
at com.test.hsql.HSQLSample.main(HSQLSample.java:41)
```

When I specify properties in server.properties file and then connect using jdbc call , I am successful. But I am not getting reason , why I am getting error when I specify all properties while creating server itself in java code.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: The code you have posted so far looks correct - can you show how you are actually starting the HSQLDB server instance?

Comment: I call server.start() . When I use default user and password that sa,"" respectively , I am able to create database . But problem occurs when I try to have other user than sa.  The same works through server.properties file where I specify user and password in url

Comment: When I call `server.start()` using your code, I see the following output: `[Server@90affe]: Database [index=0, id=0, db=file:/sampledb/ipl5, alias=ipl5] opened sucessfully in 639 ms.` Can you verify that you are getting a similar line that includes the database alias?

Comment: @krautmeyer -- My username was incorrect and since , I was pointing to different file , I didnt notice that.  Thanks for verifying . I was able to connect with db after correcting username